# file_per_tablespace is possible for myisim storage engine.make ibd files for myisam storage engine

Tags: mysql

I have one table which is having myisam storage engine.
create table temp1(code varchar(20),primary key (code))engine =MyISAM;want to create ibd files for the same.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not really understand your question! Myisam storage engine does not use ibd files to store data, it uses myd files. Ibd files are for innodb tables. Do you want to convert the table to innodb?

Comment: ok .thanks dr..i try to convert table to innodb

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you need to do is set `innodb_file_per_table=1` in your config and rebuild the table. That will make the table a separate ibd file instead of it being in the master tablespace.